# How to use Perl-compatible regular expression to remove XML tag off XML text in PHP?

Tags: php, xml, regex, preg-replace, posix

I have this XML content:

```
$XML = "<item xmlns='http://...'>Some value</item>";
```

I want to extract the value off the tag, so I use the following regular expression:

```
$Value = preg_replace("/^<item [.]+>/","",$XML);
$Value = preg_replace("/</item>$/","",$Value);
```

But these don't work, the $Value finally is still the same as $XML. How to fix this?

Comment: Why not use a proper XML parser instead?

Comment: coz my xml content has only 1 tag

Comment: Using regular expression to parse XML can lead to unespected results. For exemple, if a string with a "&" character is a possible value for the item element, the "&" is escaped as &amp; in well formed XML and the regular expression won't get rid of this entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract the text inside the tag you can use this code:

```
$string = "<item xmlns='http://...'>Some value</item>";
$regex = '#<.*?>(.*?)</.*?>#';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1][0];
echo $matches;
```

If you want to use preg_replace, use this code:

```
$Value = preg_replace("/^<item .+?>/","",$XML);
$Value = preg_replace("/<\/item>$/","",$Value);
```

Comment: im i mistaken between posix regex & perl-compatible regex?

Comment: @PaulDinh This regex: <.*?>(.*?)</.*?> is compatible with every language(if you need, you have to escape the '/' with '\/').

Comment: pls how to do the same thing with preg_replace instead of preg_match_all. the xml has only 1 tag.